# When using multiprocessing in python increasing the ratio of consumers to producers is never leading to them keeping up with the work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Here's what I am trying to do: the producers are generating a value (basically iterative hashing) that is then hash mapped to "bins". The producer places each number into two bins. The consumers are each in charge of a set address range of the bins. The producer places the random number into a work queue for the consumer in charge of the appropriate address range (doing so for both bins the number is mapped to). The consumer takes jobs off its queue and performs a modulo exponential using them then moves on to the next job.

My Problem comes in when running tests to try and determine what kind of ratio of consumers to producers I will need in order to keep the queues from constantly growing in size. I found that a 1:7 ratio of producers to consumers kept the queues from growing. But then a 2:14 did not. In fact there did not seem to be a reasonable point at which the consumers could do enough work to stop the number of items in the queue from growing linearly. I did find that increasing the consumers would slow the growth of the queues but never stop it. Now I do not necessarily expect to be able to double the producers and just double the consumers too but I did expect to be able to find a ratio that was not 2 vs hundreds. To clarify I'm running this code on the cloud and so am able to ensure that there is a cpu to run each process individually.

Here is how I am creating the processes and the functions that they are being given. I'm using the multiprocessing library for creating and handling the processes and queues.

```
import hashlib
import math
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Process, JoinableQueue, cpu_count
from gmpy2 import mpz, powmod, is_prime, bit_set
from random import randint, getrandbits
from secrets import token_urlsafe
from queue import Empty

class Blake2b(object):
    def __init__(self, output_bit_length=64, salt=None, optimized64=False):
        self.output_bit_length = output_bit_length

        digest_size = math.ceil(output_bit_length / 8) # convert to bytes
        if salt is None:
            self.hash = hashlib.blake2b(digest_size=digest_size)
        else:
            self.hash = hashlib.blake2b(digest_size=digest_size, salt=salt)
        self.output_modulus = mpz(2**(self.output_bit_length - 1)) # integer double the size of the bit length - 1 (so double -2)

    def generating_value(self, preimage): 
        h = self.hash.copy() 
        h.update(preimage)  
        current_digest = h.digest()

        while True:
            U = int.from_bytes(current_digest, sys.byteorder) % self.output_modulus 
            candidate = bit_set(self.output_modulus + U, 0)

            if is_prime(candidate):
                return candidate

            h.update(b'0') 
            current_digest = h.digest()

    def KeyGen(self, preimage, size):
        h = self.hash.copy()
        h.update(preimage)
        digest = h.hexdigest()
        return int(digest, 16) % size

def task(bins, task_queue, ident, f):
    while True:
        try:
            next_task = task_queue.get(timeout=0.5)
        except Empty:
            print('Consumer: gave up waiting...', file=f, flush=True)
            continue
        if next_task is None:
            # Poison pill tells it to shutdown
            print (f'Consumer {ident}: Exiting', flush=True, file=f)
            task_queue.task_done()
            break
        
        value, in_bin = next_task
        N, A = bins[in_bin]
        answer = powmod(A, value, N)
        bins[in_bin][1] = answer

        task_queue.task_done()
    return

def add_to_queue(tableSize, num_consumers, task_queues, f):

    bit_length = 86 #The security parameter
    b = Blake2b(output_bit_length=bit_length)
    leftKey = Blake2b(output_bit_length=10, salt=b'left')
    rightKey = Blake2b(output_bit_length=10, salt=b'right')
    bins_per_process = tableSize // num_consumers

    while True:
        rnd_val = b.generating_value(token_urlsafe(16).encode('utf-8'))
        KeyLeft = leftKey.KeyGen(str(rnd_val).encode('utf-8'), tableSize)
        KeyRight = rightKey.KeyGen(str(rnd_val).encode('utf-8'), tableSize)
        
        task_queues[KeyLeft//bins_per_process].put([rnd_val, KeyLeft % bins_per_process]) 
        task_queues[KeyRight//bins_per_process].put([rnd_val, KeyRight % bins_per_process]) 
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_cpus = cpu_count()
    num_consumers = 16
    num_producers = 2
    table_size = num_consumers*8 #how many bins total

    with open("qGrowthTests.txt", "a") as f:
        table = [[getrandbits(3072), randint(2, 2**3072 - 1)] for _ in range(table_size)]
        bins_lst = [table[(i * len(table)) // num_consumers:((i + 1) * len(table)) // num_consumers] for i in range(num_consumers)]

        task_queues = [JoinableQueue() for _ in range(num_consumers)]

        producers = []
        for i in range(num_producers):
            producer = Process(target=add_to_queue, args=(table_size, num_consumers, task_queues, f))
            producers.append(producer)
            producer.start()

        consumers = []
        for queue_num, queue in enumerate(task_queues, start=0):
            process = Process(target=task, args=(bins_lst[queue_num], queue, queue_num, f))
            consumers.append(process)
            process.start()

        # checking the size of the queues once every 5 seconds for a 5 minute test
        n = 1
        while n < 60: # 5 minutes = 300 seconds, 300/5=60
            time.sleep(5)
            for q_num, q in enumerate(task_queues, start=0):
                print("Queue ", q_num, " has: ", q.qsize(), file=f)
            n += 1

        # Force all the processes to finish
        for process in producers:
            if process.is_alive():
                print (f'Producer {process}: Exiting', flush=True, file=f)
                process.terminate()
                process.join()

        for process in consumers:
            if process.is_alive():
                print (f'Consumer {process}: Exiting', flush=True, file=f)
                process.terminate()
                process.join()
    
    print('Test Complete')
```

When I tested the time it takes to do a set amount of work (giving 2 producers a number of jobs, time them, then have the consumers work through the queues), I found that that the consumers half the amount of time they take to do the same work when I double their number (expected behaviour). For instance 4 consumers take half the time as 2 consumers, 8 consumers half the time of 4 and so on. Extrapolating this I get that it should take a ratio of 2:16 for the consumers to be working through the tasks as fast as the producers are creating them. However when I run the code for five minutes having the producers do as many jobs as they can in that time with 16 or more consumers I still see linear growth of the queues. For example when running with 16 consumers the final size of all of the queues range from 450000-470000,items so all fairly close in size.

I've looked at ensuring that the producers are giving even amounts of work to all of the consumers. Also that the items are even actually being removed from the queues. I've tried using concurrent futures process pools and a manager to handle the queues and while all of those processes will complete at the same time its seems to me that there is overhead forcing that outcome because those take longer to perform the same number of tasks and when I check cpu load most are at 30% load while the code is running. Whereas with the way I create the processes as above they are at 100%.

I've tried to figure out what about my code might be wrong but I can't see what is so different about 2 producers that they are creating more work than even 42 consumers can keep up with. I think there might be something fundamental about how multiprocessing works that I am missing but I can't see what. Thoughts?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When the queue keeps growing, which queues are growing? Are all the queues growing at the same rate? Or are only some of them growing? Also, can you provide the missing `Blake2b` import statement so we can reproduce it?

Comment: I added the code for the Blake2b import, the class that is being called is there now, sorry about that. I also updated the question about the queues but the queue for each consumer is growing and at the end of a test they are all reasonably close in size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue stems from the implementation of `multiprocessing.Queue`, which internally uses a separate thread for exchanging elements. However, your producer (`add_to_queue`) occupies the GIL (Global Interpreter Lock), inhibiting the operation of this thread and preventing the exchange of elements.

This can be confirmed on the consumer side as follows:

```py
def task(bins, task_queue, ident):
    while True:
        try:
            next_task = task_queue.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            print(f'Consumer: gave up waiting... {task_queue.qsize()=}, {task_queue.empty()=}', flush=True)
            continue
```

```
Consumer: gave up waiting... task_queue.qsize()=19185, task_queue.empty()=True
```

Although `qsize` was large enough, `get_nowait` failed to fetch any elements.

The simplest solution is to use `multiprocessing.Manager().JoinableQueue()`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

...

    # task_queues = [JoinableQueue() for _ in range(num_consumers)]
    task_queues = [Manager().JoinableQueue() for _ in range(num_consumers)]
```

However, the manager is slow. If you prioritize performance, you should compare throughput and see if the difference is acceptable to you.

Another solution is to limit the queue size:

```py
    task_queues = [JoinableQueue(maxsize=1000) for _ in range(num_consumers)]
```

When the queue is full, the GIL is assuredly released, so it produces at a constant pace on average. However, with this approach, the queue is always full, making it impractical to determine the ratio of consumers from the queue size, as you are currently doing.

In this case, it would be better to compare how long it takes to process, say, one million elements. If the number of consumers is sufficient, increasing it further will not change the processing time.

Comment: Just to clarify my understanding here, when the queue size is limited that is forcing the GIL to release the queue once it is full so that the consumer can start pulling from it and the producer will just hang with its next element to be added to a queue until the queue is no longer full?

Comment: @LLL That's correct. This means that even if there are enough consumers, the queue will always be (almost) full.